# When I render in cycles white background comes out

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have been struggling to solve this I cant make it more than a week so can you help me out? Actually when I finish all stuff and start rendering in cycles it start to show me white so if you have any solution please help me!
[image]

Comment: The plane object appears to have a white material, thus it is reflecting a portion of the light it is receiving in the scene. What do the shader nodes for the plane look light? How is the lighting set up? Is the scene color management exposure set above 0? Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. What are you supposed to get instead of white? How did you set up your materials? What kind of lights are you using? How bright are your lights? Remember that no one else but you knows what you did, so we're going to need your help to help you.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/